# Reactjs, How to compare props.location.pathname to a string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, comparator, string-comparison

In my router, I need to do the following:

```
if (props.location.pathname !== '/confirm') {
    // redirect to /confirm to force the user to confirm their email
}
```

The if statement is not acting as expected.

If I output:

```
console.log(props.location.pathname)
```

I get in the console.

```
/confirm
```

However, `props.location.pathname` with the value of '/confirm' is not being seen as the same as `/confirm`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `typeof props.location.pathname` ? Strict comparison `a !== b` is true if types are different.

Comment: `typeof props.location.pathname` returns string

Comment: Then it should be ok to use `props.location.pathname !== '/confirm'`. Make sure you don't have some space or special character in "/confirm".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

type of both the operands should be same while using == for comparision.Make sure both are of string type or change if to

```
if (props.location.pathname != '/confirm') {
// redirect to /confirm to force the user to confirm their email
```

}

Answer (score 4):

To compare two strings in React.js, you can simply use **triple-equals** (or ===) as below:

```
if (stringTemp === 'desired string'){
      console.log('Equal');
    }
```